# How to solve following partial differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Let $[\xi^i]$ and $[\rho^j]$ be two coordinates system in $\Bbb{R^n}$;$1\leq i,j\leq n$.And $\xi^i=\xi^i[\rho^1,..,\rho^n]$ and $\rho^j=\rho^j[\xi^i,...,\xi^n]$ then
If we have $\frac{\partial^2\xi^k}{\partial\rho^r\partial\rho^s}=0$ then this is equivalent to the conditions that there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and an $n-$dimensional vector $B$ such that
$$\label{eq:1}
\xi(p)=A\rho(p)+B \tag{1}
$$
for all $p\in \Bbb{R^n}$.
Can someone explain how we got \eqref{eq:1} and why we are calling it an affine transformation, I am a bit confused here. If you present an example that will be a great help.

Comment: Integrate the equation twice from $0$ to $\rho$

Comment: if we first integrate with respect to $\rho^s$ then we will get $\frac{\partial\xi^k}{\partial\rho^r}=A$ where $A$ is an $n\times n matix$? Is it correct?

Comment: Why have you deleted your previous question that was exactly the same? You should have edited the first instead

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be of class $\mathcal{C}^2$.
Consider the map $g=df - d_0f \colon \Bbb R^n \to L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ of class $\mathcal{C}^1$, where $L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ is the vector space of linear functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$.
The differential of $g$ is therefore a continuous map $h=dg \colon \Bbb R^n\to L(\Bbb R^n,L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R))$.

If $E,F$ and $G$ are vector spaces, we have a natural isomorphism $L(E,L(F,G)) \simeq B(E\times F,G)$, where this latter space is the set of bilinear maps $E\times F\to G$, given by
$$
\ell \longmapsto \left[ \, (u,v) \longmapsto  \ell(u)(v) \, \right].
$$
In our case $E=F=\Bbb R^n$ and $G=\Bbb R$, and any bilinear map $b \in B(\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ is uniquely determined by the matrix $M_b=(b(e_i,e_j))_{1\ldots i,j\ldots n}$.
Indeed, we have
$$
\forall u,v\in \Bbb R^n,\quad b(u,v) = u^T M_b v.
$$
Now, note that (I leave it to you as an exercise)
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n,\quad M_{h(x)} = \left[\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}(x)\right].
$$
Hence, by assumption, $h=dg\equiv 0$.
By the mean value inequality, we have that $g$ is constant.
Since $g(0) = d_0f - d_0f=0$, it follows that $g\equiv 0$.
Therefore, we have show that
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n,\quad d_x f = d_0f.
$$
Finally, note that the map
$$
x\mapsto f(x) - d_0f(x) - f(0),
$$
has its differential that identically vanishes, so that it is constant, equal to its value at zero, that is, $0$.
Hence
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n, f(x) = d_0f(x)+f(0).
$$

Now, if $F\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^2$, write
$$
f = \begin{bmatrix}f^1\\\vdots\\f^m\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume that,
$$
\forall k\in \{1,\ldots,m\}, \forall i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\},\forall x \in \Bbb R^n,\quad \frac{\partial^2 f^k}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}(x) = 0.
$$
Then by our previous study,
$$
\forall k \in \{1,\ldots,m\}, \forall x\in \Bbb R^n,\quad  f^k(x) = d_0f^k(x) + f^k(0), 
$$
and it follows that
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n,\quad F(x) = Ax + B,
$$
with
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \nabla f^1(0)^T\\ \vdots \\ \nabla f^m(0)^T\end{bmatrix}\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R), \quad B = f(0) \in \Bbb R^m.
$$
It is called affine since it **obviously** generalizes affine functions $y=ax+b$.

Your question is the specific case $n=m$, $\xi^i=f^i$ and $\rho^j=x^j$.